# Writing a function that has to wait to a callback from an event

Tags: c#, .net, events

## The problem

Consider the following code:

```
class A
{
    private int _workId;

    public void DoWork()
    {
        _workId = new Random().Next(100);
        Console.WriteLine("Starting a long process ID: " + _workId);
        LongProcess longProcess = new LongProcess();
        longProcess.StartWork();
        longProcess.OnWorkMiddle += OnLongProcessWorkMiddle;
        Console.WriteLine("At end of long process: " + _workId);
        longProcess.OnWorkMiddle -= OnLongProcessWorkMiddle;
    }

    private void OnLongProcessWorkMiddle(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In middle of long process: " + _workId);
    }
}
```

The following code is problematic in my eyes for a few reasons:

1. There is a separation of code that by logic should be grouped togeter - I'd expect `Console.WriteLine("In middle of long process: " + _workId);` to appear next to `Console.WriteLine("At end of long process: " + _workId);`, and yet, they both appear in separated functions.
2. `_workId` should by all merits a function inside **DoWork**, however, I am forced to make it a field functions to be able to access that information from inside the callback. Every additional parameter or return value would also become a field member.

## Alternative solutions

There are a few solutions that could reduce the amount of problems in this code:

**Encapsulating the function and its callback in a different class**

One of the issues I've described above were field members that aren't necessarily related to the owner class as a whole, but instead specific to the function **DoWork** and its callbacks. By encapsulating the function in its own class, we remove that unnecessary clutter and group it in its own logical group. The downside is that it requires a creation of a class from what, by merit, should've been a function. It also doesn't solve issue #1.

**Using anonymous delegates to keep in a single function**

We could rewrite the code like so:

```
public void DoWork()
{
    var workId = new Random().Next(100);

    EventHandler onLongProcessWorkMiddle = delegate { Console.WriteLine("In middle of long process: " + workId); };

    Console.WriteLine("Starting a long process ID: " + workId);
    LongProcess longProcess = new LongProcess();
    longProcess.StartWork();
    longProcess.OnWorkMiddle += onLongProcessWorkMiddle;
    Console.WriteLine("At end of long process: " + workId);
    longProcess.OnWorkMiddle -= onLongProcessWorkMiddle;
}
```

Now we no longer the need of any field members and we can keep everything nicely in a single function. However, readability-wise I find the code rather lacking as, the code (or rather its delegate) that is executed later on, appears on top.

**Using a semi-generic helper class**

In this solution I've written a semi-generic helper class to sync the execution. It allows me to write the code in the following way:

```
public void DoWork()
{
    var workId = new Random().Next(100);

    LongProcess longProcess = new LongProcess();

    var syncr = new EventSyncr();
    syncr.Sync(
        delegate { longProcess.OnWorkMiddle += syncr.EventCallback; },
        delegate { longProcess.StartWork(); },
        delegate { Console.WriteLine("In middle of long process: " + workId); },
        delegate { longProcess.OnWorkMiddle -= syncr.EventCallback; });

    Console.WriteLine("At end of long process: " + workId);
}
```

And here is the code for the helper class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Used to synchronize code that waits for a callback from a function.
/// </summary>
class EventSyncr
{
    readonly AutoResetEvent _eventCallbackEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    private Action _actionAtEvent;

    /// <summary>
    /// Executes the syncing process. This function is blocked until the event is called back (once), then it executes the 'actionAtEvent' segment and
    /// after unsubscription, exists.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="eventSubscription">The passed delegate must subscribe the event to EventSyncr.EventCallback.</param>
    /// <param name="eventCausingAction">The event causing action.</param>
    /// <param name="actionAtEvent">The action at event.</param>
    /// <param name="eventUnsubscription">Unsubscribe the event that was subscribed in the first parameter</param>
    public void Sync(Action eventSubscription, Action eventCausingAction, Action actionAtEvent, Action eventUnsubscription)
    {
        _actionAtEvent = actionAtEvent;

        try
        {
            eventSubscription();
            eventCausingAction();
            _eventCallbackEvent.WaitOne();
        }
        finally
        {
            eventUnsubscription();
        }
    }

    public void EventCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            _actionAtEvent();
        }
        finally
        {
            _eventCallbackEvent.Set();
        }
    }
}
```

While a bit on the verbose side, it does seem to me that it solves all the problems I brought up above:

The code appears just the way it is going to be executed, in its logical order and all the additional properties are self contained.

## Questions

I am curious is to what you think about the issue and the possible solutions. Which seems the best one? Is there a better way of solving the issue?

I'm aware that in C# 5, the **await** function will provide a much better solution, but we're not quite there yet :(.

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 1):

your EventSyncr class is so strange, that you should receive an extra award for this, 
just Joking ;)

But for real, you only have to create a AutoResetEvent and wait for it at the end of your code using WaitHandle.WaitAll.

At the end of your async method you have to signal the AutoResetEvent and your main thread knows, that your async process has just finished.

```
public void DoWork()
{
    var workId = new Random().Next(100);

    Console.WriteLine("Starting a long process ID: " + workId);
    LongProcess longProcess = new LongProcess();
    longProcess.StartWork();
    longProcess.OnWorkMiddle += ()=>{ Console.WriteLine("In middle of long process: " + workId);
    longProcess.OnWorkEnd += ()=>{ 
       Console.WriteLine("At the end of a long process");
       autoEvent.Set();
    };

    WaitHandle.WaitAll(new []{longProcess.autoEvent});
}
```

Comment: @VitalyB you got the idea with your "Sync" function but what you're doing with delegation in method 1 & 2 is just not meant to be done this way. @BitKFu very good answer ! e: Consider async-Threading as another good idea ;)

Comment: Thanks to the compliment, I think :). LongProcess.Start() in the code I mentioned is a blocking function, so I can't use AutoResetEvent to synchronize the threads. But you're right, if it was running (and sending events) on a different thread, it would be a viable solution. The AutoResetEvent in EventSyncr is really part of the more generic treatment... Perhaps I should've removed it because I'm aiming the questions more to single-threaded scenarios.

Comment: Regarding your code - Howcome you didn't unsubscribe from the events? Is that a bug? Or is it because you assume 'longProcess' is going to be GC'd anyway?